# Saving output of a confusion matrix to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, confusion-matrix

In R, I'm creating two separate confusion matrices and would like to write the results of each to a data frame.  Here is the setup:

```
library(caret)
```

## Confusion Matrix 1

```
lvs_1 <- c("normal", "abnormal")
truth_1 <- factor(rep(lvs_1, times = c(86, 258)),
                levels = rev(lvs_1))
pred_1 <- factor(
  c(
    rep(lvs_1, times = c(54, 32)),
    rep(lvs_1, times = c(27, 231))),               
  levels = rev(lvs_1))

xtab_1 <- table(pred_1, truth_1)
```

Now, I create the confusion matrix:

```
foo <- confusionMatrix(xtab_1)
```

I would like to save the results for Accuracy, Specificity, and Sensitivity stored in `foo` to a data frame `df`:

```
foo$overall[['Accuracy']]
foo$byClass[['Specificity']]
foo$byClass[['Sensitivity']]
```

`df` would look as follows:

```
              Accuracy   Specificity    Sensitivity
matrix_1      0.8284884  0.627907       0.8953488
```

Next, I create another confusion matrix.  The setup:

## Confusion Matrix 2

```
lvs_2 <- c("normal", "abnormal")
truth_2 <- factor(rep(lvs_2, times = c(75, 269)),
                  levels = rev(lvs_2))
pred_2 <- factor(
  c(
    rep(lvs_2, times = c(44, 42)),
    rep(lvs_2, times = c(37, 221))),               
  levels = rev(lvs_2))

xtab_2 <- table(pred_2, truth_2)
```

The confusion matrix is:

```
bar <- confusionMatrix(xtab_2)
```

I would like to be able to write the results of `bar` to `df`

```
bar$overall[['Accuracy']]      #0.8023256
bar$byClass[['Specificity']]   #0.5866667
bar$byClass[['Sensitivity']]   #0.8624535
```

The final `df` would look as follows:

```
              Accuracy     Specificity    Sensitivity
matrix_1      0.8284884    0.627907       0.8953488
matrix_2      0.8023256    0.5866667      0.8624535
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Accuracy <- c(foo$overall[['Accuracy']] , bar$overall[['Accuracy']])
Specificity <- c(foo$overall[['Specificity']] , bar$overall[['Specificity']])
Sensitivity <- c(foo$overall[['Sensitvity']] , bar$overall[['Sensitvity']])
df <- data.frame(Accuracy, Specificity, Sensitivity)
```

Or create separate df's for each matrix and use `rbind` to combine them.